# Prevent the use of (optimized copy from) the data segment to local stack data structures/array

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, embedded

I am writing some firmware and have a need to use C code without the use of a data section. This is pretty straightforward assuming one stays away from globals. Or so I thought.

I wrote something functionally similar to the following code:

```
void func()
{
    int feature_set[][2] = {
        {feature0, 1},
        {feature1, 0},
        {feature2, 0}
    };

    //Use 'feature_set' for some hardware init
}
```

In my particular use-case, `feature_set` refers to some configuration data that I need to use for initialization. Because I was creating this data set on the stack, I was expecting it to be constructed on the stack before use. I realize this would create more instructions, but that is a trade-off I am okay with in this situation.

However, after looking at the disassembly I realized it was effectively doing something like this:

```
mov ecx, <size>
lea edi, <stack addr>
lea esi, <somewhere in .data>
rep movs
```

It's pretty clear that the compiler attempted to optimize this operation by creating a const version of the structure in `.data` and just copying it to the stack when needed.

The question: is there a way to prevent this? Is there a way to tell the compiler to not use the data segment for this operation? Changing the optimization level might work, but I *do* want an optimization effort ... just not specifically with this kind of construct.

Comment: If you are on an embeded system your compiler will probably have some pre proseesor directives you can use to say where things should be located.

Comment: If this is firmware destined for flash memory, I would look into putting the read-only data into flash by explicitly instructing the linker, by using segment attributes or whatever. Oh, and make it `const` of course, perhaps that is all that is needed.

Comment: What is feature0 etc? Compile-time constants or run-time variables?

Comment: @Lundin, The whole array is constructed of constants.

Answer (score 6):

The initializer list must be stored somewhere, you cannot allocate it in thin air. Normally the initializer list would be in `.text`/`.rodata`. The compiler can then perhaps optimize initialization by placing `feature_set` in `.data` instead of the stack, to initialize it faster.

Anyway, you can do this instead:

```
static const uint32_t FEATURE_SET [][2] = 
{
  {feature0, 1},
  {feature1, 0},
  {feature2, 0}
};
```

Now the array should be placed in flash (`.rodata` or similar) or something in your linker settings is messed up.

And then if you need a modifyable run-time version on the stack:

```
uint32_t feature_set [ sizeof(FEATURE_SET) / sizeof(*FEATURE_SET) ] [2];
memcpy(feature_set, FEATURE_SET, sizeof feature_set);
```

Also make sure no never use some weird RAM debug build, but always download programs to flash, no matter if debug or release build.

Comment: This situation is such that I have _only_ a `text` section. My hope was that I could do without a static 'initializer' and have GCC output more instructions that do the initialization upon function enter (that is, constant moves onto the stack). The default behavior of GCC with `-O0` is exactly that, but elsewhere in the project I was `-Os` or `-O3`. I found that I could push the option for `-O0` at file scope (or just wrap the function) and that also works. I suppose it could do, but leaving the behavior of a function entirely dependent on the optimization level is not a good design.

Comment: The above is true because I do not want to write a loader at the moment. Perhaps I will later. This is a hobby project.